# Find the class name on which function is binded

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I am using the each function on 'myClass'

```
jQuery('.myClass').each(function(){

......

});
```

My HTML code is

```
<div class="myClass class2 class3 "></div>
```

My Question is in the above jquery Each Function i want to get the name of the class "myclass" which triggers the each function.if i use the `jQuery(this).attr('class')` i get the entire list of classes like "myClass class2 class3"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just store the selector string in a variable before you call `.each()`? Then you can just refer to that variable inside the callback.

Comment: If you used this selector, then you can just hardcode it since it's guaranteed it will have `"myclass"`, otherwise the callback function wouldn't be reached

Comment: It is not possible to extract which particular class among a number of classes the event was bound to. You can do it the bad way, always ensure that the class in question is the first class in the html code, the use jQuery `attr` to extract the class, then use regular expression to extract the part of the resultant string upto the first space, that will give you the class you want.

Comment: The class doesn't "trigger the `.each()` function": the first part, `$(".myClass")`, returns a jQuery object containing any matching elements, and then `.each()` iterates over that object. But `.each()` can iterate over _any_ jQuery object, including ones that didn't use a class selector (or ones that didn't use a selector at all), and if you do something like `$('.myClass').removeClass('myClass').each(...` you'll be iterating over all of the elements that had 'myClass' a moment ago but don't anymore... (So from that point of view it doesn't even make sense to ask which class triggered it.)

Comment: Is there any way to find the class name "myClass" other than hardcoding it into variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is

```js
console.log($(".myClass").selector); // outputs .myClass
```

but it will not work inside `.each()`.

You would have to resort to  a simple variable to pass the selector into the function:

```js
var selector = ".myClass";

$(selector).each(function () {
   console.log(selector); // outputs ".myClass"
});
```

After reading your comment below, you can do the following:

```
for(var i=1; i<10; i++) {
  var selector = ".myClass" + i;
  $(selector).each( function() {
     console.log(i) // will output the value of `i` at the time .each() was called
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to find the class name "myClass" other than hardcoding it into variable? Hardcoding won't work in the scenario if i use some number along with the  class name like "myclass1","myClass2","myClass3"..."myClassn" and now i want to use the each function depends on the number after that "myClass",Suppose if class is "myClass1", i want to extract that 1 from "myClass" and use it inside each function then how can i do that. Please suggest me.

Comment: Why don't you just have a format for your classes like `.myClass-<number>` so `.myClass-1`, `.myClass-2`? Then for example you can get the number by doing a simple split like `var myNumber = selector.split("-")[1];`

Comment: Thanks Strelok. Then how do i call the each function one time using the wild character, i.e i want to call  jQuery('.myClass-n').each(function(){

......

});...........here 'n' can be anynumber that i can use in my HTML. The each function should be called for myClass-1 , myClass-2...myClass-n, then how can i modify the selector?.Please Suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mohamed do not use classes to pass data around.. use data attributes.. read http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2